# Copy multiple Feature Classes using ONE CopyFeatures command

Tags: python, arcpy

My script below works fine, however, how can I combine each `copy.features` task into one?
Can I use a tool where I can simply list all the 14 feature classes I want to export in ONE LINE? Then run `arcpy.CopyFeatures_management` once underneath.

```
print "Script started..."
print "***"
print "This monthly script will back up all grounds maintenance feature classes as shapefiles."
print "***"
print "The backup folder is:"
print "K:\GIS2016\GIS_Data\Curo_data\Estates_data\Grounds_Maintenance\Grounds_Maintenance_Backups"
import arcpy
import os
import datetime
from arcpy import env


Cur_Date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d%B%Y")
print Cur_Date

print "***"
print "Setting script to overwrite previous files..."
# Overwrite pre-existing files
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


newpath = r'\\somernt\curo\GIS\GIS2016\GIS_Data\Curo_data\Estates_data\Grounds_Maintenance\Grounds_Maintenance_Backups\GM_' + Cur_Date
if not os.path.exists(newpath): os.makedirs(newpath)


print "***"
print "Starting backup process..."
env.workspace = r"\\somernt\curo\GIS\GIS2016\GIS_Data\Curo_data\Estates_data\Grounds_Maintenance\Grounds_Maintenance.gdb"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("LITTER_BINS", newpath + "\\LITTER_BINS.shp")
print "Bins"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("AMENITY_GRASS", newpath + "\\AMENITY_GRASS.shp")
print "Amenity grass"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("AMENITY_GRASS_SHELTERED", newpath + "\\AMENITY_GRASS_SHELTERED.shp")
print "Sheltered grass"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("HEDGES_1SIDE_ONLY", newpath + "\\HEDGES_1SIDE_ONLY.shp")
print "Hedges- 1 side only"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("HEDGES_1SIDE_TOP", newpath + "\\HEDGES_1SIDE_TOP.shp")
print "Hedges- 1 side and top"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("HEDGES_2SIDES_TOP", newpath + "\\HEDGES_2SIDES_TOP.shp")
print "Hedges- 2 side and top"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("LEAF_CLEARANCE", newpath + "\\LEAF_CLEARANCE.shp")
print "Leaf clearance"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("MEADOW_GRASS", newpath + "\\MEADOW_GRASS.shp")
print "Meadow grass"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("ROUGH_GROUND", newpath + "\\ROUGH_GROUND.shp")
print "Rough ground"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("SHELTERED_GRITTING_AREAS", newpath + "\\SHELTERED_GRITTING_AREAS.shp")
print "Sheltered gritting areas"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("SHRUBS_ORNAMENTAL", newpath + "\\SHRUBS_ORNAMENTAL.shp")
print "Shrubs"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("SHRUBS_WALL", newpath + "\\SHRUBS_WALL.shp")
print "Shrub wall"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("SOMER_GRIT_BINS", newpath + "\\SOMER_GRIT_BINS.shp")
print "Grit bins"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("SWEEPING", newpath + "\\SWEEPING.shp")
print "Sweeping (hard surfaces)"


print "Script finished"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [ListFeatureClasses](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listfeatureclasses.htm):

> Lists the feature classes in the workspace, limited by name, feature
>   type, and optional feature dataset.

And a for loop:

```
import os
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\TEST.gdb'
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
outfolder=r'C:\shapefilefolder'

for fc in featureclasses:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, os.path.join(outfolder,fc+'.shp'))
```

Comment: Thanks @BERA but that does need a closing bracket at the end.

Answer (score 1):

OK so here is my final code, which is tidier and works smoothly!

```
print "Script started..."
print "***"
print "This script will back up all grounds maintenance feature classes as shapefiles"
print "***"
print "The backup folder is:"
print "K:\GIS2016\GIS_Data\Curo_data\Estates_data\Grounds_Maintenance\Grounds_Maintenance_Backups"
#Import required modules
import arcpy
import os
import datetime
from arcpy import env

#Set the date format to be used in the backup folder name
Cur_Date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d%B%Y")
print "The backup folder will be called GM_" + Cur_Date

print "***"
print "Setting script to overwrite previous files..."
#Overwrite pre-existing files
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Define new folder to be created for backed-up files
newpath = r'\\somernt\curo\GIS\GIS2016\GIS_Data\Curo_data\Estates_data\Grounds_Maintenance\Grounds_Maintenance_Backups\GM_' + Cur_Date
if not os.path.exists(newpath): os.makedirs(newpath)

#Set location of feature classes to be backed-up
print "***"
env.workspace = r"\\somernt\curo\GIS\GIS2016\GIS_Data\Curo_data\Estates_data\Grounds_Maintenance\Grounds_Maintenance.gdb"
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

print "Backing up files...(please wait 2-3 minutes)..."
#Copy feature classes to newly created folder and convery to shapefile format
for fc in featureclasses:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, os.path.join(newpath,fc+'.shp'))

print "Script finished"
```